# python Number Generator generator a series of horizontal lines into a txt

Tags: python

I want to generate a series 7 numbers of horizontal lines into a txt of every possible combination from 1 to 50 how can i do that ?

so example 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 would be a set of numbers 
next set would be 8-9-12-13-14-15-16

Comment: 1-50 is 50 numbers = 7 lines with 7 digits each with one to spare. So it would not be possible. Please consider revising your question. Also, what have you done so far? Permuting 50 numbers is 50! combinations I think? That is 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000 different permutations. Are you sure that is what you want??

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're looking for, esp. because "the next set" seems to skip 10 and 11 for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following, if I understand your question correctly:

```
nums=range(50)
while len(nums)>=7:
  for i in nums[:7]:
    print(i,end="-")
  print("")#newline
  nums=nums[7:]
```

You may have to tweak it a bit to get it exactly how you want it.